# Returning async values from google maps api in a Meteor helper

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

The helper should return a google api call, but it prints `undefined` once to the console and doesn't updatewhen getting the response:

onCreated template:

```
this.distances = new ReactiveDict('restDistances');
```

helper:

```
distanceIs: function (destination, id){
    var origin = Session.get('userLatLng');
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        console.log(123);
        console.log(Blaze._globalHelpers.getDistance(Template.instance().distances, id, origin, destination));
        return Blaze._globalHelpers.getDistance(Template.instance().distances, id, origin, destination);
});
```

}

```
Template.registerHelper('getDistance', function(template, id, origin, destination){
  var map;
  var directionsDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route({
    origin: {lat: origin[0], lng: origin[1]},
    destination: {lat: destination[1], lng: destination[0]},
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode["DRIVING"]
}, function (response, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true});
      var distanceinmeter = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
      var timeInMinutes = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
      console.log(distanceinmeter); //OK
      template.set(id, distanceinmeter );
      Tracker.autorun(function(){
        console.log(template.get(id));
        return template.get(id);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('rout not found');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Typo. `Blaze._globalHelpers` not `Baze.` You also need to show that global helper code. If it's making an async call then you'll need a promise or to use the ReactiveDict in the helper.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I've fixed the type and added the helper code. thanks.

Comment: I've updated the code, and seems like everything is working alright now, all console.logs, but the result even though it's printed correctly to the console, it is not rendered on the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try the following - you don't even need a `Tracker.autorun()`.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.distances = new ReactiveDict('restDistances');
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  distanceIs: function (destination, id){
    const origin = Session.get('userLatLng');
    Blaze._globalHelpers.getDistance(Template.instance(), id, origin, destination);
    // the reactive var will automatically get updated when it is set from the
    // callback of directionsService.route()
    return Template.instance().distances.get('restDistances);
  }
});

Template.registerHelper('getDistance', function(template, id, origin, destination){
  var map, directionsDisplay, directionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsService.route({
    origin: {lat: origin[0], lng: origin[1]},
    destination: {lat: destination[1], lng: destination[0]},
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode["DRIVING"]
}, function (response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true});
      // set the reactive var to the desired value
      template.distances.set('restDistances', response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
      // there is no need to return here since it would be to the 
      // directionsServices.route callback and not the outer function

    } else {
      console.log('route not found');
    }
  })
});
```